# Convert float data to Char data that has to be sent over UDP

Tags: c, sockets, type-conversion

I'm using C socket to send data to a Server, I found some example on internet but all of them show a char data sent over the network. 
Instead, my data are float, so I need to convert these data from float to a char to send it, and on the Server side I must convert it back to float.

I read about sprintf or snprintf, but I found some problems with using these functions.

My situation:

packet[4] = {112.3, 113.4, 234.8, 599.4} "For example"

I need to send it as char to the Server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can't you `memcpy()` the contents of your `packet` to a `char buf[enoughLength]` and then pass that `buf` to `send()`?

Comment: it's a really good solution actually. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're careful, you can use a `union` for representing your `float` as an array of `char`s:

```
typedef union packet
{
    float f;
    char c[4];
} packet;
```

Barring endianness (you might have to twiddle the float) and `char` being signed on some platforms and unsigned on others (adjust to taste), this is well-defined. In particular, the standard guarantees that

1. The address of `f` is the same as the zeroth element of `c`.
2. the `c` array is contiguous.

Comment: yeah but what if the server is running on another machine? The address won't be the same! My problem is that I have two peripherals, from one I obtain 4 float values, from another 10 char type. So I should convert float to char to send it to the server running on another machine, and after re-do the conversion to float of all variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused with char buffer and char value. The char buffer which is meant in UDP communication, is 8bit/1Byte minimum space required to carry data info. This is also equal to char which is also 8bit/1Byte in size. Hence people call it as char buffer. This dosenot mean they only can carry char value.

Typical float value is 4 bytes in length and this can be carried in 4byte char buffer. Please use memcpy operation and copy the contents of float variable in to 4Byte char array buffer. In the server, based on source IP, this value could be easily type casted to float value(using atof) from received char array buffer.

```
code snippet:
//At Tx - from client
float flt =xx.xx;
char charbuff[4] ={0};
memcpy(&charbuff,&flt,4);


//At Rx - in server
if(Rx done from specific IP which sends float value)
{
float rflt = (float)atof(buffer); //build in function available
}
```

Comment: int main(void){
 float value= 22.3;
 char valbuff[4]={0};
 memcpy(&valbuff,&value,4);
 float values = (float)atof(valbuff);
 printf("Valore %f ",values);
} 
When I run this code the out value is 0.0000, I'm trying first with a sample program, before using it in Socket programming.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int main(void)
> {
>     float value= 22.3;
>     char valbuff[4]={0};
>     memcpy(&valbuff,&value,4);
>     float values = (float)atof(valbuff);
>     printf("Valore %f ",values);
> }
> ```
>
> When I run this code the out value is 0.0000, …

Since you just copied the `float value` to the `char valbuff[4]`, the `atof(valbuff)` to put the value back into a `float` is quite out of place; you rather need

```
    float values;
    memcpy(&values, valbuff, sizeof values);
```